# Angular cdkFocusInitial focus fired on dialog backdrop

Tags: angular, accessibility

We are using `cdkFocusInitial` on some of our input elements inside a dialog to overwrite the default focus like:

```html
<mat-form-field class="address-field" *ngIf="!createNewAddress">
  <mat-select #deliveryAddress placeholder="{{ 'order.dialog.create.details.label.delivery-address' | translate:locale.language }}" [attr.cdkFocusInitial]="filteredAddresses.length > 1 ? true : null" (focus)="expandDeliveryAddress($event)"
                (selectionChange)="handleAddressChangesInSelectList($event)" formControlName="deliveryAddress" tabindex="0">
    <mat-option class="address-option" *ngFor="let address of filteredAddresses; let i = index" [value]="address">
      <div class="address-option-div">
        <div class="address-text"><h5>{{ address.firstName }} {{ address?.secondName }} {{ address?.thirdName }} </h5></div>
        <div class="addresses"><h6>{{ address.street }}, {{ address.streetNumber }}, {{ address.zipCode }}, {{ address.city }}, {{ address.country.name }}</h6></div>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

expandDeliveryAddress function:

```js
expandDeliveryAddress(): void {
    if (this.addresses.length > 1) {
        this.deliveryAddress.open();
    }
}
```

This works as expected. The dropdown get's expanded when there is more than one address available and auto selects if only one (not shown here).

But `expandDeliveryAddress` is also called when backdrop is clicked. Better said `(focus)` is because this also happens on normal `mat-input` fields.
I'm not sure how to prevent this. I inspected the event object send but there is nothing that helps me to find if that event was backdrop click.

Hope somebody can help me with this.